# Multiply digits of number of list python

Tags: python, list, split, digits

I have array of 3 digit prime numbers:

```
for num in range(100, 1000):
     if num > 1:
         for i in range(2, num):
             if (num % i) == 0:
                 break
             else:
             numere_prime.append(num)
```

the list is:

```
numere_prime = [[101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163...]
```

What I need is multiply each digits of a number (ex 101 = 1 * 0 * 1) and then it shows all numere_prime that after multiplying is equal to user input.
what i made so far:

```
    for elem in numere_prime:
        digits = [int(x) for x in str(elem)] # split digits into [1,0,1][1,0,3]...
        for n in list(digits):
            // n * n_at_next_index * n_at_next_index
            if //result of multiplying == //number set by input:
            //append digits to result list
```

result should be like:`input (9) = [191, 313, 331, 911]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
primes = [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163]
a = int(input('enter a nmber :'))
primes_useful = []
for i in primes :
    product = 1
    for k in str(i):
        product *= int(k)
    if product == a :
        primes_useful.append(i)

print(primes_useful)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your prime algorithm is wrong.  You can't just append to list when ANY factor fails, you have to know that ALL of the factors fail.  And you don't have to search all the way to `num`; you only have to search up through `sqrt(num)`.  Since the largest value is 1000, you can stop at 33.  Also, it's silly to check for `num > 1` since you start the range at 100.  And you don't have to convert `digits` to a list; it's already a list.

You could make this a bit shorter by using the `any` function inside `get_primes`, and by using `yield` in the `filter_primes`.  You'll get to that later.

```
def get_primes():
    numere_prime = []
    for num in range(100, 1000):
        prime = True
        for i in range(2, 34):
           if (num % i) == 0:
              prime = False
              break
        if prime:
           numere_prime.append(num)
    return numere_prime

def filter_primes(primes, magic):
    res = []
    for elem in primes:
        digits = [int(x) for x in str(elem)] 
        product = 1
        for n in digits:
            product *= n
        if product == magic:
            res.append(elem)
    return res

numere_prime = get_primes()

inp = int(input("Your value: "))

result = filter_primes(numere_prime, inp)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numere_prime = []
for num in range(100, 1000):
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            prime = False
    if prime:
        numere_prime.append(num)


def prime_digit_prod(x):
    output = []
    for elem in numere_prime:
        digits = [int(x) for x in str(elem)] # split digits into [1,0,1][1,0,3]...
        result = 1
        for n in digits:
            result *= n
        if result == x:
            output.append(elem)
    return output

print(prime_digit_prod(9))
```

output:

```
[191, 313, 331, 911]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numere_prime = [101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157]
digi_mult_dict = {}
for elem in numere_prime:
    c = elem % 10
    b = int((elem % 100 - c)/10)
    a = int((elem - b - c)/100)
    mult = a * b * c
    digi_mult_dict[elem] = mult
numero = input("input a number")
for key, value in digi_mult_dict.items():
    if int(value) == int(numero):
        print(key)
```